# MySQL query where a column equals another column of previous row

Tags: mysql

I have a table of people with these fields: `id`, `name`, `parentId`, `spouseId`. The latter two are nullable.

I need to retrieve the whole family from that info alone and I already have a query that traverses down the family tree, then I can recursively query its results by `id`:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE people.id = ? OR people.parentId = ? OR people.spouseId = ?
```

Problem is, this doesn't traverse upwards. I need to be able to also select where `people.id = previous_person.parentId` with one query.

I can't just call the traverser for the parent after it traverse the descendants because the entire thing is asynchronous and doing it means I have to do it in a callback.

Comment: How far do you want to recurse? Until the values are 'null', or just one level? Would this not be easier to perform in your programming language?

Comment: @Mr47 Until the query comes up empty.

Comment: why don't you use mptt?

Comment: @e4c5 Because I'm not using Django, or Python for that matter.

Comment: MPTT means modified pre order tree traversal and that has nothing to do with django or python. There is an excellent tutorial online for mysql+php